# xtype: combo is not firing expand event

Tags: extjs, expand, xtype

I am working on `EXTJS 3.4` version and facing an issue with `xtype: combo`.

For some records it is going to expand event for some not.

**My code is like below:**

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    labelWidth: 0,
    store: this.comboBoxStore,
    mode: 'local',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    displayField: 'asupDate',
    minListWidth: 500,
    valueField: 'asupId',
    itemSelector: 'div.search-item',
    forceSelection: true,
    editable: false,
    width: 180,
    id: 'combo' + '-' + this.ptype + '-' + this.asupRecord.get('sysRefId'),
    listeners: {
        expand: function () {
            //stop special keys operations... like j, k and 1,2,3,4.
            this.getEl().addListener('keydown', me.onKeyDownFunction);
            //Call loadAsupRange to load/populate asupRange dropdown.
            var cdvMainPanelObj = Ext.ComponentMgr.get('cdvMainPanel');

            if (!Ext.isDefined(me.asupRecord)) {
                var seriallNo = me.systemRecord.get('sn');
                var systemNo = me.systemRecord.get('sysId');
            } else {
                var seriallNo = me.asupRecord.get('sysSerialNo');
                var systemNo = me.asupRecord.get('sysId');
            }
            cdvMainPanelObj.loadAsupRange(this, systemNo, seriallNo, me.ptype);
        },
        render: function () {
            Ext.QuickTips.register({
                target: this.id,
                text: utp_toolTips.cdv_dropdown_asupRangeCombo
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know what I did wrong.

Comment: I don't see anything that you did wrong, but then, I don't get the full picture. Can you create a Sencha Fiddle that exhibits the problem?

Comment: I actually can't, i am working on existing code.. new to extjs, for some data its fine.. for 1 url its not allowing me toopen the dropdown... tried click, change, select events as well.. nothing working

Comment: I guess we cannot help you if you cannot share the minimum required information with us.

Comment: You can check how and where "me" is defined. Your reference to "me" in "expand" listener can be problematic.

Comment: hit F12 try to check in any errors fired when you try to expand the combo

Comment: I tried F12 there is no error or exception.. its simply not going to expand event

Comment: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2gb8 expand event is firing. Make sure if keydown function is not empty function at runtime.